# Broadcasting and receiving messages with UdpClient

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, udpclient

I'm playing around with broadcasting and receiving UDP messages.
I have a client and a server that work ok in my machine, but that can't connect across machines.

My server sends messages and my client receives them.
I turned of the firewall on both machines, that can't be the problem.

The server looks like:

```
var udpclient = new UdpClient();

IPAddress multicastAddress = IPAddress.Parse("239.0.0.222");
udpclient.JoinMulticastGroup(multicastAddress);
var endPoint = new IPEndPoint(multicastAddress, 2222);

while(true)
{
    Byte[] buffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Dns.GetHostName());
    udpclient.Send(buffer, buffer.Length, endPoint);

    Console.WriteLine("Broadcasting server hostname: {0}", Dns.GetHostName());
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
```

And the client looks like:

```
var client = new UdpClient { ExclusiveAddressUse = false };

var ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 2222);

client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
client.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;

client.Client.Bind(ipEndPoint);

IPAddress multicastaddress = IPAddress.Parse("239.0.0.222");
client.JoinMulticastGroup(multicastaddress);

Byte[] data = client.Receive(ref ipEndPoint);
string strData = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data);
Console.WriteLine("Received hostname {0} from the server", strData);

Console.WriteLine("I'm done. Press any key to close me.");
Console.ReadLine();
```

I think the problem is not in the code, but network related.
Any ideas on how to check what's the problem? Thank you in advance

Comment: Try doing a TCP connection first and see if you can get them to talk to each other. UDP is a connection-less protocol and does not guarantee messages will arrive at their destination.

Comment: My idea is to connect a server and a client without them knowing of each other. The server broadcasts its IP via Udp, the client picks that up and establishes a tcp connection with the server. But I can try TCP, just for the test. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score -2):

Try connecting them to a same network such as a wifi network.Note: every time you connect to a different network the IP address changes.